# Is there a way to be recursive through different types of ProtoBuf fields?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, protocol-buffers

I am trying to create a diff between [protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) messages that would work along all the [IMessage](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/interface/google/protobuf/i-message-t-?hl=en) objects (as far as I can tell the interface every protobuf implements) in the codebase.

To this end, I have made a generic method that would take any `IMessage` implementation (that provides a parameterless constructor) and would attempt to create a delta.

```
public class ProtocolDiffer<T> where T : IMessage, new()
{
    public T Diff(T original, T replacement)
    {
        var delta = new T();
        foreach (var fieldDescriptor in replacement.Descriptor.Fields.InFieldNumberOrder())
        {
            // Obtain the pair of values to compare
            var originalFieldValue = fieldDescriptor.Accessor.GetValue(original);
            var replacementFieldValue = fieldDescriptor.Accessor.GetValue(replacement);
            Console.WriteLine(
                $"Is the field {fieldDescriptor.Name.ToUpper()} equal between Original and Replacement? " +
                $"{originalFieldValue.Equals(replacementFieldValue)}");
            // These fields are equal, jump to the next pair
            if (originalFieldValue.Equals(replacementFieldValue)) continue;
            // They were not equal
            // Is it a simple field?
            if (fieldDescriptor.FieldType == FieldType.Message)
            {
                // Non-basic fields need to be evaluated instead of simply replaced
                fieldDescriptor.Accessor.SetValue(delta,
                    Diff((T)(IMessage) fieldDescriptor.Accessor.GetValue(original),
                        (T)(IMessage) fieldDescriptor.Accessor.GetValue(replacement)));
            }
            else
            {
                fieldDescriptor.Accessor.SetValue(delta, fieldDescriptor.Accessor.GetValue(replacement));
            }
        }

        return delta;
    }
    ...
}
```

The issue I am having is that the recursive mechanism fails since eventually the object being treated changes from the class that were generated through protoc to a `RepeatedField` and the `Diff` will not be able to cast the objects.

I have tried using `IMessage` as the parameter to instantiate this `Diff` class but it does not provide a parameterless constructor. I am now considering creating a class that implements `IMessage` that would be able to be cast to by the protoc generated classes and [RepeatedField](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/collections/repeated-field-t-?hl=en) but that will still take some time and I am unsure if I would even be able to provide the necessary casting in the first place.

Finally, this is all being done so that I can return the difference between two structures, including primitive fields and complex ones such as Lists, the idea being that the recursive mechanism would traverse the whole structure until it replaces every different field and then returns the structure with only those same fields set.

Is there a way to fix the casting issue so I can keep using the recursive mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you will need to simply deal with repeated fields (and maps) as separate branches in your generic diff method.

The [IsRepeated attribute](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/reflection/field-descriptor#isrepeated) of a `FieldDescriptor` will tell you "in advance" whether a field is repeated or not. Likewise [IsMap](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/reflection/field-descriptor#ismap) for maps. The [GetValue](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/interface/google/protobuf/reflection/i-field-accessor#getvalue) documentation tells you what you can convert the returned objects to:

> For repeated values, this will be an IList implementation. For map values, this will be an IDictionary implementation.

The exact details would depend on how you want to define what a diff between two repeated fields (or maps) is. For example, you might want to apply your recursive diff process to matching pairs (list indices, or map keys), but it's not entirely obvious what the `delta` result should contain for elements that have been removed in the replacement (nothing?), or added in it (a copy of the entire added message?). For a repeated field, you might also need to add placeholder items (default instances?) even for equal elements, otherwise the caller would not know which list indices contained the non-equal ones.

Finally, I don't think the recursive step in your example is correct. It assumes the submessage is also of type `T`, which isn't particularly likely. If the field has some *other* message type, the recursive call would need to return a `delta` of that type, not a `T`.

One possibility would be to write a method that's purely based on reflection, with the following general shape (not a complete example):

```cs
public IMessage Diff(IMessage original, IMessage replacement, out bool changed) {
  // new, empty message of the same type; not sure if there's a cleaner way
  IMessage delta = replacement.Descriptor.Parser.ParseFrom(ByteString.Empty);
  changed = false;
  foreach (var fieldDescriptor in replacement.Descriptor.Fields.InFieldNumberOrder()) {
    if (fieldDescriptor.IsMap) {
      var originalMap = (IDictionary<object, IMessage>) fieldDescriptor.Accessor.GetValue(original);
      var replacementMap = (IDictionary<object, IMessage>) fieldDescriptor.Accessor.GetValue(replacement);
      // ...your desired logic for comparing two maps...
    } else if (fieldDescriptor.IsRepeated) {
      var originalList = (IList<IMessage> fieldDescriptor.Accessor.GetValue(original);
      var replacementList = (IList<IMessage> fieldDescriptor.Accessor.GetValue(replacement);
      // ...your desired logic for comparing two lists...
    } else if (fieldDescriptor.FieldType == FieldType.Message) {
      var originalMessage = (IMessage) fieldDescriptor.Accessor.GetValue(original);
      var replacementMessage = (IMessage) fieldDescriptor.Accessor.GetValue(replacement);
      bool fieldChanged;
      var fieldDelta = Diff(originalMessage, replacementMessage, out fieldChanged);
      if (fieldChanged) {
        changed = true;
        fieldDescriptor.Accessor.SetValue(delta, fieldDelta);
      }
    } else {
      var originalValue = fieldDescriptor.Accessor.GetValue(original);
      var replacementValue = fieldDescriptor.Accessor.GetValue(replacement);
      if (!originalValue.Equals(replacementValue)) {
        changed = true;
        fieldDescriptor.Accessor.SetValue(delta, replacementValue);
      }
    }
  }
  return delta;
}
```

For slightly better type safety, you could wrap that inside your proposed `ProtocolDiffer<T>` class to ensure that two messages of the same type are always passed in, and to indicate that the output will also be of the same type.

You might also drop the `out bool changed` out parameter and use the `Equals` method before the recursive step to determine if a field needs to be included in the outgoing `delta` message, like you're doing in your example. But that does a little more work than is necessary, because it involves performing a deep equality check on each "level" of the recursion.

Comment: You are correct, I ended up having to opt into two methods to differentiate between lists and non-list elements.

Besides that, I had the issues you described with defining what a delta might or might not be.